# Iterating through all values of df to replace zero values

Tags: python, pandas, replace, iteration, nan

I want to iterate through all values of a df so that if it detects some zero, I can replace that specific element with the mean of the adjacent columns.

> 

I tried this code but I dont know why isnt working. Somebody can help me, please??

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import numpy as np

d = {'col1': [4, 1, 2], 'col2': [1, 0, 4], 'col3': [12, -2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)


for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in list(df):
                if df.loc[i,j] is np.nan:
                        df.loc[i,j] = (df.loc[i,j-1] + df.loc[i, j+1])/2
```

So that 0 in the position 2x2 of the matrix would be replace with the mean between 1 and -2 (the elements at the same line and adjacent columns)

Comment: You basically never want to iterate over a dataframe

Comment: Maybe first use `print()` (and `print(type(...))`, `print(len(...))`, etc.) to see which part of code is executed and what you really have in variables. It is called `"print debuging"` and it helps to see what code is really doing.

Comment: I don't like `list(df)` - it should give column's name - but later you try to do `j-1` which means `column_name - 1` and this will raise error because you have `string - int`.

Comment: using `print()` I see it has problem to compare `df.loc[i,j] is np.nan`. It has to be `if np.isnan(df.loc[i,j]):`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a couple of small things, but I hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
d = {'col1': [4, 1, 2], 'col2': [1, np.nan, 4], 'col3': [12, -2, 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

rows, cols = df.shape
for i in range(rows):
        for j in range(cols):
                if np.isnan(df.iloc[i,j]):
                        df.iloc[i,j] = (df.iloc[i,j-1] + df.iloc[i, j+1])/2
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to replace `list(df)` by `range(len(df.columns))`

and `df.loc` by `df.iloc`

```py
for i in range(len(df)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
                if pd.isnull(df.iloc[i,j]):
                        df.iloc[i,j] = (df.iloc[i-1,j] + df.iloc[i+1, j])/2
```